# Need to place icon as button at the top right of the label in swift

Tags: swift4

I tried to put the image as button at the top right of the label that yo out side the label with autolayots but when I run the app the button would be too far from the text . But I need the button to apper exactly after text at top-right.I want something like in the image[button at top right of label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZdz9.jpg)

Comment: get any solution? I am having same problem...

Comment: Sorry for late reply, the solution is don't give width to label and attach button constraints to the label